# Having a lot of errors while trying to create new porject in Android Studio 3.5.3

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I want to create a project in Android Studio 3.5.3 by using Kotlin, but I've got a lot of errors.

the first error is:

```
Could not find androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0.
Required by:
    project :app
```

After a lot of searching I added maven to repositories:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

    }
}
```

now I get these errors:

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: constraintlayout-solver
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

I don't know what I should do to eliminate these errors. I've tried many ways but I couldn't solve these errors.

this is my `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: please share your build.gradle file

Comment: make sure you have a working internet while creating project. try Clean Project, Rebuild Project